# How to avoid flash before entering next route with loading in react router?

Tags: react-router

I would like to use `prepare` to prepare next page before entering route and at this point a loading page is shown.

I have tried to use `useLocation` and `useEffect` but next page will flash in before loading page is shown.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const location = useLocation(); // react-router

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    prepare(() => setLoading(false)); // callback when `prepare` is complete
  }, 0);
}, [location.pathname, prepare, setLoading]);

return (
  <Switch>
    {routes.map((route) => (
      <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={route.path}
        render={() => loading ? '' : <route.component />}
      />
    ))}
  </Switch>
);
```

Currently I am using a dirty solution `DelayedComponent`

```
const DelayedComponent = (props) => {
  const { component } = props;
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(true);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, []);

  return show ? createElement(component) : <div />;
};
```

Comment: what do you expect to see instead of blank screen in the moment of preparing?

Comment: @IT'sBruise I expect next page does not flash in before `prepare` finishes.

Comment: in other words, you expect the previous page will be shown before preparation is over? and only after that next page will be showed is it right?

Comment: @IT'sBruise not necessarily previous page actually, either previous page or a loading page is ok

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that i understood your problem correctly, but i will try to suggest something

It's your router:

```js
<Switch>
  {routes.map(({ path, component: Component }) => (
    <Route
     exact
     key={path}
     path={path}
   >
     <Component />
   </Route>
 ))}
</Switch>
```

then your any component

```js
// Users.js
import React from 'react';

import useFetchUsers from './useFetchUsers';

const Users = () => {
  const { isLoadingUsers, users } = useFetchUsers();

  if (isLoadingUsers) {
    return <LoadingWhatEverComponent />
  }

  return (
    <div>{users.map((user) => user.name)}</div>
  )
}
```

Before users are not loaded you will show loading screen

```js
// useFetchUsers.js

import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetchUsers = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios(...);
      setUsers(response.data.users);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setUsers([]);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, [])

  return {
    isLoadingUsers: isLoading,
    users
  }
}
```

as a result, before fetchUsers is not over, you can see only loading component

Comment: If `User` is one among route config list items, like `[{ path: '/users', component: require('path/to/Users').default }]`, it has a loading state (initially `true`) to display loading component. That means every route component will have a loading state, which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: @Mike mb you should add additional flag like `[{ path: '/users'. component: Users, hasPreparation: true }]` and depend on it, include preload logic or exclude. If you share more information about what is kind of preparation (it is async import of component, it's data fetching or something other)  than i can give better answer